# Time-out with jQuery.get()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way to set the timeout period in `$.get()` ?

As I want my script to give a warning that loading is taking some time (perhaps due to a busy server or whatever)
Can't seem to find it anywhere..

Comment: do you mean you want to trigger a function after a certain delay, or you want to cancel the `$.get` request after a certain delay? If it's just triggering a function, you can use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just use [`$.ajax(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(data){
        //...
   },
   timeout: 1000 //in milliseconds
});
```

Also as stated below in the comments you can use [`.ajaxSetup(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to apply the timeout globally:

```
$.ajaxSetup({timeout:1000}); //in milliseconds
```

Comment: If you want to do it globally then: $.ajaxSetup({timeout:1000});

Comment: @epignosisx that too. I will add that to the answer. ^_^

Comment: what is the best timeout? 2000ms?

Answer (score 4):

[`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is just a nice shorthand for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which has a `timeout` option, which will specify how long the script will wait before cancelling the callback.

You can override the global default using [`$.ajaxSetup({timeout: 9001})`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), which will allow you to continue to use `$.get`.

If you simply want to alert the user without cancelling the request, use `$.ajax`, set a timeout, and cancel the timeout in the `complete` callback.

Here's some example starter code, i haven't tested any of it, and it could probably be turned into a plugin with a bit of work:

```
(function(){
  var t, delay;
  delay = 1000;
  $('.delay-message').ajaxStart(function () {
  var $this;
  $this = $(this);
  t = setTimeout(function () {
    $this.trigger('slowajax');
  }, delay);
  }).ajaxComplete(function () {
    if (t) {
      clearTimeout(t);
    }
  });
}());

$('.delay-message').on('slowajax', function () {
  $(this).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

use [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
timeout:2000 // in milliseconds 
});

//your get request here
```

Answer (score 2):

Call [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and pass the `timeout` option.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.ajax()` for this; after all `.get()` is just a wrapper around this. You can do something like:

```
function doAjax() {
    var $warning = $("#warning").hide(), // Always hide to start with
        warningTimeoutId = 0;

    warningTimeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
         $warning.show();
    }, 10000); // wait 10s before showing warning

    $.ajax({
        timeout: 30000, // 30s timeout
        complete: function () {
            // Prevent the warning message from appearing
            window.clearTimeout(warningTimeoutId);
        }
        ... // other config
    });
}
```

Here you start a timeout just before the Ajax call which will be shown after 10s unless the Ajax request has already finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily display a **custom error message** when a timeout occurs (otherwise the $.get-completion callback is not called) you can use this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
            // timeout occured
        } else {
            // other error occured (see errorThrown variable)
        }
    }
});
```